# How to add a string into a tuple to create a 2 member tuple?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tuples

Let's say I have a string

```
x = '32'
```

And I already have a 1 length tuple defined with something like

```
tuple_a = ('12',)
```

I want to transform the string into a 1 member tuple and add the 2 tuples together so the outcome is something like

```
tuple_a + x = ('12','32')
```

and not something like:

```
tuple_a + x = ('12','3','2')
```

Which is all I could managed to do by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, so you cannot modify `tuple_a` to insert another element. You'd have to construct a new tuple, and assign that back to your `tuple_a` variable.

```
>>> x = '32'
>>> tuple_a = ('12',)
>>> tuple_a = (tuple_a[0], x)
>>> tuple_a
('12', '32')
```

As @iCodez mentioned, the `+` operator is defined for tuples, so you could take advantage of that too if you wish

```
>>> tuple_a = ('12',)
>>> tuple_a + (x,)
('12', '32')
```

Comment: Note that you could also do: `tuple_a += (x,)`.  It still constructs a new tuple object, but it saves typing. ;)

Comment: I know tuples are immutable, I was trying to save the result in another variable, but still wasn't able to wrap my head around it, your answer made it seem very easy and straigthforward. Thanks for the help! Certainly helped some newbie python coder :)

Answer (score 3):

How about `tuple_a + (x,)`?

```
>>> tuple_a = ('12',)
>>> x = '32'
>>> tuple_a + (x,)
('12', '32')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify a tuple. You will have to create a new one.

If you need to modify, better use a list.

```
x = '32'
list1 = ['12']
list1.append(x)
print list1  # ['12','32']
```